# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind' " after using FlatButton in kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to implement FlatButton in my kv but I keep getting the same error that is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind. It works fine with Button alone.

```
from flat_kivy.flatapp import FlatApp
from kivy.uix.touchripple import TouchRippleBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import (StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty,
ListProperty, DictProperty, BooleanProperty)


class Login(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

theRoot = Builder.load_string('''
ScreenManager:
    Login:

<Login>:
    FlatButton:
        text: 'Click Here'
        size_hint: (.4,.25)
''')

class TouchRippleApp(FlatApp):
    def build(self):
        return theRoot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TouchRippleApp().run()
```

This is the FlatButton code in Flat_Kivy. I'm stuck at this problem.

```
class FlatButtonBase(GrabBehavior, LogBehavior, TouchRippleBehavior,
                     ThemeBehavior):
    color = ListProperty([1., 1., 1.])
    color_down = ListProperty([.7, .7, .7])
    border_size = ListProperty([0, 0, 0, 0])
    text = StringProperty('')
    alpha = NumericProperty(1.0)
    style = StringProperty(None, allownone=True)
    color_tuple = ListProperty(['Grey', '500'])
    font_color_tuple = ListProperty(['Grey', '1000'])
    ripple_color_tuple = ListProperty(['Grey', '1000'])
    font_ramp_tuple = ListProperty(None)
    font_size = NumericProperty(12)
    eat_touch = BooleanProperty(False)

    def on_color(self, instance, value):
        self.color_down = [x*.7 for x in value]


class FlatButton(FlatButtonBase, ButtonBehavior, AnchorLayout):
    pass


class RaisedFlatButton(RaisedStyle, FlatButton):
    pass
```

Comment: Where is FlatButton defined?

Comment: Hi inclement, I've edited the post for the flatbutton

Comment: Is this code imported in your app?

Comment: I just tried to imported FlatButton in the KV just now. Still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an easier way to do this altogether is create your FlatButton class in the .kv language (inside your string you're loading with Builder.load_string)

Try adding this to your kv string:

`<FlatButton@Button>: # create a class "FlatButton" that inherits the kivy Button
    background_normal: "" # Get rid of the kivy Button's default background image
    background_down: "" # Get rid of the kivy Button's default background image when clicked
    # Set the background color to transparent if no action is happening to the button
    # If the button is clicked, it will change it to fully white
    background_color: (1,1,1,0) if self.state == 'normal' else (1,1,1,1)`

and then you can remove all the code relating to your FlatButton class on the python side, with the exception of creating a base class for the kv to work with. E.g. all you need in the python code is

`class FlatButton():
    pass`